# Microsoft Print to PDF not working when used comma(,) in file name

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

```
    public void RenderCanvasImage(int maxRight, int maxBottom, Canvas surface, Transform transform)
{
            RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(maxRight, maxBottom, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

            renderBitmap.Render(surface);

            PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
            {
                return;
            }

            Grid grid = new Grid();
            Image myImage = new Image();
            myImage.Source = renderBitmap;
            myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            grid.Children.Add(myImage);
            Grid.SetColumn(myImage, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(myImage, 1);

            grid.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
            grid.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), grid.DesiredSize));
            dialog.PrintVisual(grid, "My Canvas");
            surface.LayoutTransform = transform;
        }
```

I am using above code to print my canvas with **Microsoft Print to PDF**. Its working fine in all cases but when i enter comma in file name e.g.**(Print,Test)** while printing. It doesn't save my file and also not providing any **error/exception** code by which i could intimate the user to change file name.

Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, don't do it

This is a known bug when printing to PDF

Use a different driver or don't put a comma in the file name

Its not only from WPF, its in general in certain situations.

[Bug in "Print to PDF" and "Print to XPS" in Windows 10? comma in filename results in zero-byte file](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/bug-in-print-to-pdf-and-print-to-xps-in-windows-10/13e0976f-7bbe-4aec-bffe-c3cded548a49)

[Microsoft Print to PDF not working](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_tools/microsoft-print-to-pdf-not-working/45ca98f8-7df0-402e-89cc-7ae3d89aa1e8)

[Found a bug in Microsoft Print to PDF](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/found-a-bug-in-microsoft-print-to-pdf/595a2ddd-0fd0-4104-ac2c-5804cbbbaa07)

[Microsoft Print to PDF in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/microsoft-print-to-pdf-in-windows-10/60a85085-091f-4c83-b776-e9c298aa1113)

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your reply. But I am not end user, this problem occur when user put the comma in file name. How could we restrain one to not save file name with comma. What we can do is let him show a error message, but code is not returning any error code in our case. so we left with no choice.

Comment: @Praveensharma Check for comma and throw or show a dialog

Comment: I am not able to find any property in **System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog** which can provide us file path/name. So how can we show any error message to end user.  Any suggestion by which we could get the file name.

Comment: You can check if the file has 0 bytes i guess

Comment: Once print dialog is opened then we choose **Microsoft Print to PDF** from available printer list then another **FileSave** pop up is shown but we don't have control over it So my problem is that i don't have any information about which path or filename end user has selected. Is there any way where we can get that which path or filename user had entered?